# Disable cache for one model

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, nhibernate-3

I got a table which is modified by two applications. One of them is using nhibernate. How do I disable caching for that table? Can it be done in the mapping file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cache is **not** enabled by default.

If you are referring to the "first level cache", i.e. the Session, there is something wrong with your usage pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the L2 cache enabled for the session factory (via `cache.use_second_level_cache`), you should be able to exclude the `<cache>` element in your mapping file for that model.